# Rails way for relationship between two related join tables and enforcing data integrity at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design

Let's have I these following entities in my toy schema: Building, Apartment, Tenant, MaintenancePerson.

This is how these entities are related:

- Building has many tenants.
- Tenant can belong to many buildings too via Apartments.

Hence, it is essentially a many-to-many relationship between building and tenants via apartment.

Now, I'd like to add MaintenancePerson in the system. A MaintenancePerson can be associated with every level in the system.

- A MaintenancePerson can be associated with many Buildings. A building can also have many MaintenancePersons.
- A MaintenancePerson can be associated with many apartments. An apartment can also have many MaintenancePersons. This maintenance person for an apartment should be the one which is assigned to the building in which that apartment exists.

I can have these following tables:

```
Apartments
  id
  building_id
  tenant_id

MaintenancePersonBuildingAssignments
   id
   maintenance_person_id
   building_id
   <attributes>

MaintenancePersonApartmentAssignments
   id
   maintenance_person_building_assignments_id
   apartment_id
   <attributes>
```

Now, here in the maintenance_person_apartment_assignments, the building_id can be inferred from both - maintenance_person_building_assignments_id as well as apartment_id.
Also, if I use the maintenance_person_id instead of maintenance_person_building_assignments_id, I won't be able to ensure that the maintenance person already exists for that building.

What is the "Rails way" to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you had a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html to learn about the various ways ActiveRecord models relationships?

Comment: Yes, I have. This is a specific problem I have. I'd like to know the Rails recommended way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would have something like the following ActiveRecord class relationships:

```
class Building < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :apartments
  has_many :tenants, through: :apartments
end

class Apartment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :building
  belongs_to :tenant
  has_and_belongs_to_many :maintenance_persons
end

class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :apartments
end

class MaintenancePerson < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :apartments
end
```

To support the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `Apartment` and `MaintenancePerson` a join table called `apartments_maintenance_persons` would exist with `apartment_id` and `maintenance_person_id` columns.